# Slow WiFi on one device due to poor hardware

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, desktop-computer

I have two computers. A laptop and a desktop. Speed test on the laptop shows a download speed of 156Mbps. Speed test on desktop shows a download speed of 2Mbps. I can also see the difference in speed while using these devices.

I tried to google the reason but none of the solutions talk about poor hardware. I strongly suspect that my desktop has poor hardware. But I have no idea about the hardware components.

Which hardware component manages WiFi? Is there a good way to know if the slow WiFi speed is due to poor hardware?
I want to know so that I can replace this hardware component.

Comment: What is the model of the WIFI adaptor (find it in device manager) and what model router do you have?

Comment: Wifi adaptor is intel Dual Band wireless-AC 3168.

Comment: Additional information on the hardware in both devices would help.  Also the router you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few reasons that "hardware" could slow WiFi transfer. Here are some suggestions for testing.

- Physical location, i.e., distance and signal path to the router and nearby radio frequency interference, are likely causes. Move the router or desktop within a few meters of each other, without intervening walls, panels or cabinets, and check the speed.
- Interference on a particular WiFi channel could be a problem; try a different channel at the router.
- If there's no benefit from moving things around or changing channel, then the WiFi card could be a limiting factor. You can experiment with an external USB WiFi adapter. Borrow an adapter, or buy one, to test. For example, [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008IFXQFU) claims 150 Mbps speed and is US$8.
- CPU capabilities may also be a limitation, but you'd need to discover the capabilities of the PC's. Since you've provided no information, it's impossible to provide help on that.

Comment: I experimented with physical location and concluded that it is not the reason. CPU capability is fine. I have 8GB RAM and most of the memory is free as per task manager. So most likely, the reason is due to poor Wifi Card.

Comment: Perhaps... test a WiFi "dongle" to see if that is true.

Comment: got a new wifi card. worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

That's a huge difference but I've seem something similar. Luckily for you, the problem is on the desktop and not the laptop, since the latter are much more difficult and sometimes impossible to upgrade.

Just to be sure it is not caused by an outdated driver, I recommend you download the latest drivers for  you hardware. If you don't know what it is, then you have to open the *Device Manager* if you are on Windows. There are instruction for different versions of Windows [here](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000833.htm).

It is very likely that the hardware is simply old. One system here when from 80 to 320Mbps by doing such a hardware upgrade. What you need to by is a WiFi adapter to replace the one currently on your system. The latest WiFi 6 standard is the fastest, known as 802.11ax and the one before that is 802.11ac, both which can go much faster than what you quote for your laptop. The speed will be limited by the network, so you won't get 802.11ax speeds if your router does not support that standard but eventually you will when upgrading it.

What you should look for is a *Network Card*. Personally, I have had a very good experience with the [Intel AX200NGW from MQUPIN](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07ZRN3L34/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&th=1) and so I bought two of them. Initially I order 2 different adapters to try them out but returned a Ubit AX2200 which refused to work. There are probably other good ones but the ones I kept worked flawlessly under Windows and Linux, so I feel comfortable recommending them.

When you get the new card, try to install the new one without removing the old one first, so that you can use the older adapter to download the driver for the new one. Otherwise, it's a bit of a hassle but that's what I did and downloaded the driver onto another computer and moved it by USB-key. Another possibility is to use an Ethernet cable if you have one to connect directly to your router since some computers only have a slot for one of these adapters.

Comment: new Network card might be the solution for me. is it easy to remove the existing one and replace it with a new Network card? do you recommend any tutorial for this?

Comment: It's very easy. It involves unscrewing the antennas from the back which required no tools, just turn the base. Then inside there is a single standard screw holding the card in place. Since you can see where the antennas come out, you know which card it is. Getting into the case usually involves zero to 3 screws, all are the same standard Philips-type. This one pretty much explains it: https://win10faq.com/how-to-remove-your-wifi-card/